# Delete a value form JSON object using .map function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object:

```
[{"box":1,"parent":[],"child":[{"boxId":2},{"boxId":3}]},{"box":2,"parent":[{"boxId":1}],"child":[]}]
```

I want to remove a `"child":[{"boxId":2}` with boxId=2. I am using ,map function like this:

```
Arr.map(function (box) {
  box.child.map(function (p) {
    p.remove();
  });
});
```

It doesn't work. I get error.

> .remove is not a function`

Is there any way I can delete a specific element?

**EDIT**

Eg: I would like to delete `{"boxId":2}` from child and the resulting JSON should be:

```
[{"box":1,"parent":[],"child":[{"boxId":3}]},{"box":2,"parent":[{"boxId":1}],"child":[]}]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What should be the expected JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var arr = [{"box":1,"parent":[],"child":[{"boxId":2},{"boxId":3}]},{"box":2,"parent":[{"boxId":1}],"child":[]}];

// Loop over main array
arr.map(function(e) {
  
  // Get the child element array and iterate over it
  return e.child.forEach(function(c, i) {
    
    // If box to remove found
    if (c.boxId === 2) {
      // Remove the element from main array element
      delete e.child.splice(i, 1);
    }
  });
});

console.log(arr);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Could you please help me to delete entire box based on id, fr eg: if I want to delete box 2 the resulting JSON would be : `[{"box":1,"parent":[],"child":[{"boxId":2},{"boxId":3}]}]`

Comment: @Arti You want to delete element on it's `box` value and not `boxId` value in `child`?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply :-). No. I want to do both first delete box having id say 2 and then delete child which has 2.

Comment: You answer correctly answers the question I posted but in addition to that I would also like to delete based on box id.

Comment: @Arti Use `filter`. `arr = arr.filter(function(e) {
    return e.box !== 2;
});`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var removedId = 2;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = data[i].child.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (data[i].child[j].boxId == removedId) 
            data[i].child.splice(j, 1);
    }
}
console.log(data);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ztud4vjf/)